Can we connect to group inputs sockets using python
I was able to create a HSV node and make everything in a group.
Now I want to connect Hue , sat , value to the group input using python.
My job requires to do this for many assets. Hoping that I can make it automate.
Any help will be appreciated


Why are the 3 links red? Is this an error? Shouldn't they be grey? - About your question: yes, this should be doable. Do you want to create the links in the group or outside where the group is used?

Red color is from theme. I want to create link inside group. I am till that point where I can create a group a hsv node with python . But unable to connect socket using code.
Normal node connection is easy maybe group there is something else.
